# Noncommutative version of Littlewood's First Principle

Tags: functional-analysis, von-neumann-algebras, noncommutative-geometry

There are definitely noncommutative analogues for Lusin's theorem and Egoroff's theorem (found in Blackadar for example).  I'm curious if there is a version of the first principle:

Every Lebesgue
measurable set is almost an open set.

In this noncommutative setting, I wonder if this is just saying that a von Neumann algebra is densely spanned by its projections (this is certainly true)... but is this the appropriate analogy?

Comment: See recent work of D. P. Blecher et al on open projections (they are believed to be the right non-commutative analogues of open sets). Then you should for statements like every projection is a limit of open projections in somesence

Comment: I asked him today..... he said he'd have to think about it

Comment: If this question requires even a minute thought of him, I doubt you'll get an answer here

Comment: Should I ask it on overflow?

Comment: Of course!$\phantom{}$

Comment: Dear Norbert, please inform me too whenever you got.